# Расстояние между строками. Qt QPainter::drawText

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте! Вывожу текст на печать через QPainter::drawText. Подскажите как можно изменить интервал между строками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! `QPainter` предоставляет только высокоуровневое API по управлению выводом текста на экран, чтобы иметь возможность более тонко влиять на процесс вывода текста необходимо использовать класс [QTextLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextlayout.html). Вот пример из документации:

```
 int leading = fontMetrics.leading();
 qreal height = 0;
 textLayout.beginLayout();
 while (1) {
     QTextLine line = textLayout.createLine();
     if (!line.isValid())
         break;

     line.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
     height += leading;
     line.setPosition(QPointF(0, height));
     height += line.height();
 }
 textLayout.endLayout();
 // ...
 QPainter painter(this);
 textLayout.draw(&painter, QPoint(0, 0));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Такой вариант меня не совсем устраивает. Уже сделал так как советуют тут http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?218371-How-to-change-line-spacing-in-QPainter-drawText